# Given a prime number $p$, prove that there exists infinitely many prime number $q$ which is congruent with 1 by modulo $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Can anybody help me to solve the problem as stated in the title:

> Given a prime number $p$, prove that there exists infinitely many prime number $q$ which is congruent with 1 by modulo $p$.

I am helping my nephew in the secondary school to learn mathematics, but this problem seems too difficult to me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you familiar with [Bezout's identity]( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity )?

Comment: Thanks! I just check the Bezout's identity, but it consider only the existence. The problem here is that "there exists infinitely many..."

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I misread the problem

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: There is a much easier proof for the $1\pmod{n}$ progressions, even easier when $n$ itself is prime.  See here : http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec12.pdf

Comment: Thanks! But the proof for Dirichlet's theorem is very advanced. Is there any solution so that a secondary school pupil can understand it?

Comment: @TrungTa even for prime modulus, I do not think there is an easier proof than the one in the link I gave.  For prime modulus follow the steps of the proof in the link and assume $n$ is prime, it simplifies a lot.  I doubt there is anything simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I will check it out!